# The role of time-reversal in detailed balance

Tags: statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium, stochastic-processes

For a stationary stochastic process (representing the internal time-evolution of a certain physical system which on average is stationary) we speak of detailed balance when, roughly speaking, the probability of every event is equal to the probability of the time-reversed event.

It is clear that having a partition $P$ of all events in subsets of pairs which "compensate one-another" has profound implications: e.g. the short-range correlations* in extended equilibrium systems, fluctuation-dissipation theorems, reciprocity theorems...

In many of these implications, it seems a priori not clear that the subsets in the partition $P$ must consist of an event $X$ and its time-reversed counterpart $\theta X$. E.g. to have short-ranged correlations in the stationary state one might be satisfied with another sort of partition $P$ where the subsets' cardinality is still somehow small though possibly larger than 2. I think many examples where such a "generalized" detailed balance occurs are known (chemical networks, zero-range processes...).

**Q**: Concerning the implications of detailed balance, where is the aspect of "pairwise/'local' cancellation" more significant and where is the ingredient of time-reversal in the detailed-balance cake redundant?

(*In large scale systems, long-range correlations are also present in equilibrium at critical points in the phase-diagram. But those critical regions represent exceptional conditions, as stipulated by the Gibbs phase rule.)